# Add an extra value to a dict key

Tags: python

If have to following dict:

```
graph = {'A': ['B', 'C'], 'B': ['C', 'D']}
```

How can i add an extra value to (for example)  key a (so the result will be

```
graph = {'A': ['B', 'C', 'Z'], 'B': ['C', 'D']}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your values in the dictionary are lists. Thus the following works:

```
>>> graph['A'].append('Z')
```

`list.append()` adds an item to the end of the list.

Example:

```
>>> graph = {'A': ['B', 'C'], 'B': ['C', 'D']}
>>> graph['A'].append('Z')
>>> graph
{'A': ['B', 'C', 'Z'], 'B': ['C', 'D']}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, add "Z" element to list:

```
graph["A"] += "Z"
```

Comment: That will work, but sort of accidentally.. try it with `"ZA"` or `2` instead of `"Z"`.

Comment: Yes, `+=` is more of a shortcut for `.extend` than `.append`.

Comment: This is right. My answer was usefull only in this context.